# android exception in SplashScreen

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

```
    package com.example.activity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import com.example.NewActivity.PhoneNumberRegistration;
    import com.example.aayushchaubey.meetdax.R;

    public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                /*
                 * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
                 * want to show case your app logo / company
                 */

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                    // Start your app main activity
    //                ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SplashScreenActivity.this);
    //                progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    //                progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
    //                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    //                progressDialog.show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, PhoneNumberRegistration.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // close this activity
                    finish();
                }
            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        }
    }
```

error is :-

```
art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #55 pc 000000000026770c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+184)
       art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #56 pc 0000000000288634  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+564)
       art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #57 pc 00000000002b80a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE2ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+612)
       art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #58 pc 00000000002abd78  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+17508)
       art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #59 pc 0000000000261a14  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+484)
       art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #60 pc 000000000054bee8  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+812)
       art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #61 pc 00000000000dc1ac  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
       art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #62 pc 00000000008f8618  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (???)
       art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.example.activity.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:16)
       art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6992)
       art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
       art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
```

When Splashscreen is openining its app is getting crash.In this line its showing error but its not showing error message in logcat(new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()).This is the logcat its showing after the app is crashed.

Comment: Where is your stack trace please?

Comment: Post your logcat so we can help.

Comment: I don't believe it shows nothing in logcat

Comment: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #62 pc 00000000008f8618  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (???)
       art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.example.activity.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:16)
       art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6992)

Comment: By looking at the imports I think there should be a problem with your PhoneNumberRegistration class. This code looks fine to me.

Comment: k i will post PhoneNumberRegistration.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks good, There may be issue in importing R files.

**Delete**

```
import com.example.NewActivity.PhoneNumberRegistration;
import com.example.aayushchaubey.meetdax.R;
```

**Import** class file again using `Alt+Enter` import class.

Register `SplashScreenActivity` and `PhoneNumberRegistration` to manifest file.

Clean and Rebuild Run it again it may solve your problem.

Comment: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.example.aayushchaubey.meetdax

Comment: I am pretty much sure there is issue in importing of class files.

Comment: what is NewActivity in importing PhoneNumberRegistration Post PhoneNumberRegistration class.

Comment: PhoneNumberRegistration is available under NewActivity directory